# Neo4j: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher, list-comprehension

The following request

```
MATCH (n:artist) 
RETURN  [(:tag { _id : 'jazz' })-[:TAGS]->(n) AND (:tag { _id : 'pop' })-[:TAGS]->(n) | n._id] AS ids
```

returns the following error:

```
Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 104 (offset: 103))
```

I have absolutely no clue on what's wrong, it seems like the problem is with the "AND" as this query works fine:

```
MATCH (n:artist) RETURN  [(:tag { _id : 'jazz' })-[:TAGS]->(n) | n._id] AS ids
```

**Neo4j version:**  3.3.4

Comment: What version of Cypher (or Neo4j) are you using?

Comment: The later query you listed is valid, but only for newer Cypher versions. (I believe list comprehension, the `| n._id` part, was added in version 3.1)

Comment: @Tezra I use the latest version (my db is hosted on graphendb) and yes the last query works, but not the first one (and I need to chain AND in my use case)

Comment: So you want something like `with ["pop","rock","jazz"] as tags MATCH (t:tag { _id : 'jazz' })-[:TAGS]->(n:artist) WHERE t._id IN tags RETURN n._id` right? (I didn't notice the AND in the first query at first. ^^;)

Comment: Also the error looks the same as if you where using an older version of Neo4j, so that's why I checked that first =P

Comment: @Tezra won't the proposed solution using the `IN` syntax return all n._ids that are tagged by at least one of the tags? It sounds like OP wants only the `n`s that are tagged by all of the given terms, not just one. Although I like the succinctness of your solution far better than mine.

Comment: @RebeccaNelson Yes... That is an OR query. I would actually recommend using the `... WHERE ALL(tag in tags| (:tag { _id : tag})-[:TAGS]->(n)) ...` pattern, as that is easier to read, and kinder to the Cypher planner.

Comment: @Tezra that is some good info; I'm gonna go ahead and add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `AND` in a pattern expression; it must go in a `WHERE` clause. You cannot put `AND` in the middle of two patterns. Usually, you would convert their constraints to WHERE syntax and put them in that clause; however, for your particular case, the query can be rewritten as a single pattern.

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:artist) 
RETURN  [(:tag { _id : 'jazz' })-[:TAGS]->(n)<-[:TAGS]-(:tag { _id : 'pop' }) | n._id] AS ids
```

And if you need to search for multiple tags, you can put additional tags in a `WHERE` clause directly after the main pattern in the list comprehension:

```
MATCH (n:artist) 
RETURN  [(:tag { _id : 'jazz' })-[:TAGS]->(n)<-[:TAGS]-(:tag { _id : 'pop' }) WHERE (:tag { _id : 'mytag1' })-[:TAGS]->(n) AND (:tag { _id : 'mytag1' })-[:TAGS]->(n) AND ... | n._id] AS ids
```

Finally, this solution, proposed by @Tezra, checks that each tag in the given list is searched for. It could be more performant for your queries; I'd recommend using `PROFILE` with each style to find the one that works best for you:

```
WITH ['jazz', 'pop', 'tag1', 'tag2', ...] AS tags MATCH (n:song) WHERE ALL(tag in tags WHERE (:tag {_id: tag})-[:TAGS]->(n)) RETURN n._id;
```

This will return a stream of IDs. To put all of the IDs in a single list returned as one value, replace the `RETURN` clause of the above statement with `RETURN COLLECT(n._id)` (suggested by @Emilien).

Comment: Well, I feel quite dumb as using AND seemed so natural it did not even came to my mind that this wouldn't be allowed !

I actually need to chain `AND` so this query would not work for me...  I tried to figure out a working `WHERE` alternaive but I failed...

Comment: @Emilien no problem! You can put patterns in a `WHERE` clause as well; I'll update my answer to show how to adapt this to multiple (more than two) tags.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, I was trying this but with the (n) alone before the `WHERE`, I guess I have really bad intuitions for Cypher lists...

Comment: @Emilien happy to help! Note that the solution I proposed might get the job done but it might not be very efficient. I would highly recommend looking at Tezra's comments under your question.

Comment: One final performance note, if you are checking against a dynamic list frequently, the WHERE ALL/ANY/NONE(...) pattern can be used with query parameters, allowing the Cypher planner to plan once, and execute many. Dynamic AND chaining prevents Cypher from re-using previous plans.

Comment: @Rebecca, the la solution does not return a list, I'd suggest you add `collect(n._id)` so that it truely answers the question :)

Comment: @Emilien you are completely correct. I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue in Neo4j Cypher Query while loading data from CSV file. In my case, there were near about 20 node properties. I was getting the error message

> "Invalid input 'P': expected whitespace, comment, NodeLabel, MapLiteral, a parameter, a parameter (old syntax), ')' or a relationship pattern (line 2, column 20 (offset: 90))"

Query syntax was right.

Solution: It was working just moved long query to multiple lines by by just hitting enter button.
An yes it worked for my case.